# Formatting List into string

Tags: c#, string, list

So im running a little issue with my code, how can I convert my List into a normal string with this format

```
listitem1, listitem2, listitem3
```

Note that last listitem3 does not have a , at the end.

I tried String.Inser but I cant get the last index..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sound like you need [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)

```
var result = string.Join(", ", yourList);
```

Comment: Regarding the disputed edit: It was before .NET version 4.0 (not 4.5) you had to call `ToArray()` to hit an overload of `Join` that existed then.

Answer (score 1):

Use a join which will concatenate your array with a delimiter which you define.
Likewise use a split to turn your delimited spring into an array.

```
var list = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};

var stringList = string.Join(", ", list);
```

the result will be

> one, two, three

If you want the space make sure to include it in the delimeter `", "`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a foreach loop, to get last item then based on that append a comma :

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("Test1");
mylist.Add("Test2");
mylist.Add("Test3");

string lastItem = mylist[mylist.Count - 1];
foreach(string s in mylist)
{
    if (s != lastItem)
    Console.Write(s + ", ");
    else
    Console.Write(s);
}
```

and the result is:

```
Test1, Test2, Test3
```

Comment: You don't say what `sw` is (Edit: I see you changed your answer.). Note if some intermediate list items are equal to the last item, they will not get a comma.